# SQL помогите. Ошибка по полю en

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql9.5

```
SELECT product.*,CAST (options->>'power' AS FLOAT ) AS "en" 
FROM "product" 
LEFT JOIN "manufacturer" ON "product"."manufacturer_id" = "manufacturer"."id" 
WHERE ("en" >= 100) 
GROUP BY "product"."id"
```

ERROR:  column "en" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t"."manufacturer_id" = "manufacturer"."id" WHERE ("en" >= 10...
                                                             ^

Comment: как вы думаете, сначала выполняется `where` или `select` ?

Comment: первый идет where?

Comment: Посмотрите, значить, в справку... почти (с) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html

Comment: Просто я использую QueryBuilder в yii2 и там не важно что первое что второе...

Comment: я не о yii2 и queryBuilder а о том, как СУБД выполняет запрос. Поскольку сначала записи фильтруются в WHERE,  то СУБД знать не знает, что и как вы там поименовали в SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в порядке выполнения инструкций.
Как гласит [документация](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#AEN83201)  порядок выполнения выглядит следующим образом:

1. Все запросы в списке `WITH`. Они служат в качестве временных таблиц, на которые можно ссылаться в списке FROM. Запрос `WITH`, на который ссылаются более одного раза в FROM, вычисляется только один раз, если не указано иное с `NOT MATERIALIZED`.
2. Вычисляются все элементы в списке `FROM`. (Каждый элемент в списке
   `FROM` - это реальная или виртуальная таблица.) Если в списке `FROM`
   указано более одного элемента, вычисляется декартово произведение.
3. Если указано предложение `WHERE`, то все строки, не удовлетворяющие
   условию, исключаются из выходных данных.
4. Если указано предложение `GROUP BY` или имеются вызовы агрегатных
   функций, выходные данные объединяются в группы строк, совпадающих по
   одному или нескольким значениям, и вычисляются результаты агрегатных
   функций. Если предложение `HAVING` присутствует, оно устраняет группы,
   которые не удовлетворяют данному условию.
5. Фактические выходные строки вычисляются с использованием выражений
   `SELECT output` для каждой выбранной строки или группы строк.
6. `SELECT DISTINCT` удаляет повторяющиеся строки из результата. 
   `SELECT DISTINCT ON` удаляет строки, соответствующие всем указанным
   выражениям. `SELECT ALL` (по умолчанию) вернет все строки-кандидаты,
   включая дубликаты.
7. Используя операторы `UNION`, `INTERSECT` и `EXCEPT`, выходные данные
   нескольких операторов SELECT можно объединить для формирования
   единого результирующего набора. Оператор `UNION` возвращает все
   строки, которые находятся в одном или обоих результирующих наборах.
   Оператор `INTERSECT` возвращает все строки, которые строго находятся в
   обоих результирующих наборах. Оператор `EXCEPT` возвращает строки,
   которые находятся в первом результирующем наборе, но не во втором.
   Во всех трех случаях повторяющиеся строки исключаются, если не
   указано все.
8. Если указано предложение `ORDER BY`, возвращаемые строки сортируются в
   указанном порядке. Если `ORDER BY` не задан, строки возвращаются в том
   порядке, который система считает наиболее быстрым для получения.
9. Если указано предложение `LIMIT` (или `FETCH FIRST`) или `OFFSET`,
   оператор `SELECT` возвращает только подмножество результирующих строк.

Если указано значение для обновления, без обновления ключа, для общего доступа или для общего доступа ключа, оператор SELECT блокирует выбранные строки от одновременных обновлений.

Вы должны иметь право выбора для каждого столбца, используемого в команде `SELECT`. Для использования функции `FOR NO KEY UPDATE`, `FOR UPDATE`, `FOR SHARE` or `FOR KEY SHARE` также требуется право на `UPDATE` (по крайней мере для одного столбца каждой выбранной таким образом таблицы).